# Understanding and specifying op-amp and transistor spec to deliver maximum current from input to output

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, current-source, single-supply-op-amp

I have the circuit below working in LT Spice and on a breadboard. It appears to be working as expected - but I'm now at my theoretical limits so I need some help developing and testing it from here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD5lz.jpg).

My question: When selecting components to develop this circuit - what are the most important op-amp and transistor specs I should be looking at to ensure it can get as much input current to the output as possible? You're welcome to specify some potential components.

I need a single-supply, non-inverting, summing op-amp config that outputs voltage at unity gain - but that is also capable of handling 'as much current as possible' (sorry I can't specify an exact figure here at this point).

It will combine the DC outputs of multiple renewable energy sources e.g. solar panels, wind turbines, etc. I'm currently testing it with two small solar panels that each output a maximum of approx. 12V and 7W but I need to significantly increase that.

It'll eventually run off a 24V supply. - I know the op-amp won't output 24V with that supply but I think that's fine for this application for now.

It will be connected to a MPPT charge controller which will be charging a 12V (or possibly 24V) battery - so it needs to provide enough current from input to output for that to happen 'optimally'.

The schematic below is where I'm at right now [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD5lz.jpg). It's based on a combination of a single-supply summing config [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugWrU.jpg) and a buffer that I also see described as a current booster [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN9KW.jpg). I understand the summing config is not technically 'unity gain' but V In == V Out.

For now - I'd be happy seeing this circuit getting 2x 12V inputs @ 50W ea. from input to output if that's possible?

[image: Final Config]

1: Current Config: Single Supply, Non-Inverting, Unity Gain Summing Amp w/- Current Buffer/Booster

[image: Non-Inverting Summer]

2: Design reference 1: Single Supply, Non-Inverting, Unity Gain Summing Amp

[image: Current Booster]

3: Design reference 2: Current Buffer/Booster

[Microchip: Non-Inverting Summing Amplifier](https://skills.microchip.com/introduction-to-operational-amplifiers/691903)

[Electronics Hub: Non-Inverting Summing Amplifier](https://www.electronicshub.org/summing-amplifier/#Non-Inverting_Summing_Amplifier)

[Renesas: Boosting Op-Amp Output Current](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/r13an0008-boosting-op-amp-output-current)

[All About Circuits: How to Buffer an Op-Amp Output for Higher Current](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-buffer-an-op-amp-output-for-higher-current-part-1/)

Comment: Please draw a block diagram. Is the 5 V summing just some intermediate step to make your MPPT happen? It sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: @winny The question relates specifically to op-amp and transistor spec and selection for the schematic shown in "1: Current Config"

Comment: *I should be looking at to ensure it can get as much input current to the output as possible?* The input current does not or should not, flow to the output.

Comment: Sure, but what's your end goal? Summing 5 V supplies and driving the output from a different 24 V source isn't it. Are you aware that any 5 V sources will not provide any power to your output?

Comment: @Andyaka Given that I've said "It appears to be working as expected - but I'm now at my theoretical limits so I need some help" - it would be helpful if you could offer something to explain your answer or at least give me something to help develop my understanding? Thanks.

Comment: @winny End goal: "I'd be happy seeing this circuit getting 2x 12V inputs @ 50W ea. from input to output if that's possible".

Comment: @winny WRT to the +5V signals - a 12V solar panel might output anything between 0V and >12V. The 5V inputs are just to show the circuit is operating at unity.

Comment: You won't be transferring any power from input to output according to your schematic.

Comment: When you say "input current" do you mean the current coming from the 5 V source (that's what would normally be meant by input when discussing op-amp circuits) or from the 24 V source (which is presumably your solar cell)?

Comment: @ThePhoton In the top "Current Config" schematic - 'input current' would refer to the current flowing into R9 and/or R10. e.g. if I have a 12V/10W solar panel as an input to R10 - I would expect approx. 0.8A to be flowing into R10 and my aim is to have approximately that same current available at the Emitter output of Q2 junction with R13. Thanks.

Comment: @robobozo, that's not how op-amps work. The current into R9 or R10 should be nearly 0.  At the most, it will be a fraction of a milliamp (depending on the difference between the two inputs labelled "+5V"). This circuit isn't meant to transfer power from the +5V terminals to the output. Instead it uses the +5V input to control the power transferred from the +24 V power supply to the output.

Comment: With 5 volts across R9 or R10, you will only get 0.5 mA flowing through the resistor.

Comment: @ThePhoton. Well that's thrown me. I thought I was taking the standard inverting summing op-amp config (which takes the input voltage/s and gives a summed, gained, inverted voltage at the output), then converting it to single supply config (i.e. non-inverting), then adding a BJT buffer to the output?

I don't have the experience to disagree with you (and there's other people here also saying it won't work) but I'm seeing V In = V Out on the sim and the breadboard so I'm struggling to understand how this circuit is transferring power from VCC to Output rather than from Input to Output.

Comment: Your opamp is basically decoupling the input from output or buffering as we like to call it. All output current will come from your +24 V source and next to nothing from your inputs. Again, please draw a block diagram of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @winny Ironically, I posted a block diagram a couple of months ago (the last time I had any time to work on this) and mostly what I got was replies saying "THIS WONT WORK - YOU NEED TO POST A SCHEMATIC!!! :)

I appreciate your input and I did try to make it clear I was at the edge of my ability.   

Thanks.

Comment: The closer you are to a specific solution, the more you need a schematic. On the other hand of the spectrum for concepts, block diagrams rule.

Answer (score 2):

For handling high power, none of your designs are very good.

If you want to handle over 1 A, then with a BJT at Q2 your op-amp will need to supply at least 10 mA, and should be designed to handle 100 mA. Needing to supply 100 mA means you will need to use one of a limited number of high-power op-amp types.

It would be better to change the BJT over to a MOSFET. Then, at least at steady state, the op-amp won't need to supply any current at all. You will have to watch that as you choose higher-power MOSFETs, the gate capacitance tends to increase, and the circuit stability may suffer. You might end up wanting to have an op-amp, buffered by a BJT or a smaller MOSFET, to drive your big MOSFET.

You'll also need to carefully manage the thermal dissipation of the MOSFET as your output power increases. With 24 V input and 5 V output, the MOSFET will be consuming nearly 4x as much power as the load, and heating proportionally. Realistically, to get above a few watts of output power, you will want to change to a switching design rather than your linear design.

Comment: I'm still working through this - but I just wanted to say thanks for taking the time and making the effort to give an answer and some insight. Even off I don't walk away from this thread a qualified EE - I'll still have learnt something.

So frustrating on SO  - so many people more heavily invested in tearing apart people's questions than answering them. Ugh!!! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I agree that you do not have a summing amplifier, also you do not have a unity gain amplifier.

2. Did you look at the datasheet of the little 2N5550 transistor? Its maximum allowed output current is only 600mA (0.6A) and its maximum allowed heating is only 0.625W.
   Then your circuit powered from 24V and with a 10V output will overheat the transistor if its output current is over (0.625W)/(24V-10V)= 45mA (0.045A).

[image: boost]

Comment: TLDR: Yes - you're right. I spent so long trying to write and edit my post knowing the majority of replies would be more interested in finding fault with my question than trying to offer any help answering it that it ended up so long and so full of clarifications that it no longer made any sense - so I edited out the part that clarified what you've said here. Based on my limited understanding it divides the sum of the inputs by the number of inputs (2 in this case) then gains them by R15 and R16 (2 in this case). Unity gain - no, but for the config in "1: Current Config" V In == V Out.

Comment: And regards the 2N5550 - I started with that because it had the highest current output of the small selection of transistors I had available here to breadboard this with. My question did specifically ask for suggestion on better options. Thanks.